# TestNg priorities/ group-by-instances="true" not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Am using latest version of testng. And I have 2 test classes with 4 @Test methods as below.

```
class TestClass1 {
    @Test(priority = 0, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test1 of TestClass1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2 of TestClass1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("Test3 of TestClass1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("Test4 of TestClass1");
    }
}

class TestClass2 {
    @Test(priority = 0, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test1 of TestClass1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2 of TestClass1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("Test3 of TestClass1");
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, alwaysRun = true)
    public void test4() {
        System.out.println("Test4 of TestClass1");
    }
}
```

My TestNg.xml

```
<suite thread-count="2" verbose="10" name="testSuite" parallel="tests">
<test verbose="2" name="MytestCase" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sampleTests.TestClass1" />
        <class name="com.sampleTests.TestClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

when I run my TestNg.xml output is

```
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.141 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where in I have total 8 @Test methods but its just executing the 1st test of each class and ignores the remaining tests, without any stack-trace.

Comment: are you getting it when you call it as Maven Test ?

Comment: @Ishita Shah - ya am executing using mvn commands.           mvn test. If I don't use group-by-instances="true" then it executes priority 1 test cases 1st from each class then priority 2 test cases then priority 3 test cases., instead of executing priority 1,2,3 of 1st class and priority 1,2,3 of 2nd class

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in TestNG. Looks like it cannot correctly initialize your suite because you force it to group test by instance but priority is a cross class attribute that should be respected also. As result it cannot decide what should be run next.

Any way, it would be better to use groups and dependsOnMethod/Group options instead of priorities.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connectivity with group by, for this issue.

Its cause of main class binding. Multiple classes under single class, where TestNG starts priority with Java class name and next on.

You can resolve things by multiple way:

- **Don't Keep @Test under Java binded class. And keep separate both classes, You will be have successful execution of 8 Test.**

[image]

- **Remove priority from Java binding class.** 
  priority executes only single Test in Java Binding class.

  [image]

Both cases having different Test execution, Prefer it as according to requirement.

**Note : This solution is applicable only if there is multiple classes under single classes. Single class with Multiple @Test works fine.**

Comment: Both 'TestClass1, and TestClass2' are two different classes. My expectation of the execution order is: 1st it should execute the     `TestClass1 => test1, test2, test3, test4`      
 and then     
`TestClass2 => test1, test2, test3, test4`              
But when I remove `group-by-instances="true"`                                                            It executes  `TestClass1 => test1, TestClass2 => test1, TestClass1 => test2, TestClass2 => test2, tTestClass1 => test3, TestClass2 => test3,  TestClass1 => test4, TestClass2 => test4`

Comment: @AtitkumarShingatalur Please review my answer. 1st solution will work.

Comment: In your 1st solution execution order is `TestClass1 =>test1, TestClass2 =>test1, TestClass1 =>test2, TestClass2 =>test2, tTestClass1 =>test3, TestClass2 =>test3, TestClass1 =>test4, TestClass2 =>test4` & in 2nd solution the execution order is meeting my requirement, but u have removed the priorities of the `@Test` here it is executing in order bcz test names are in order, but in my project my test names are different, & I want them to execute in order, so I need priorities & I need output as `TestClass1 =>test1, test2, test3, test4` & then `TestClass2 =>test1, test2, test3, test4`

Comment: TestNG version am using is 6.14.3

Comment: @Atitkumar Shingatalur have you find any solution to the above.